# Publish build artifacts to OneDrive

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is it possible to publish the output from a build on Visual Studio Team Services to OneDrive storage? In my case it would be the VSTS project owner's OneDrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add a PowerShell script task in your build definition to upload the files to OneDrive via PoswerShell. For the PowerShell script, you can refer to this link for details: [How to upload large file to OneDrive by Rest API via Powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-upload-large-file-1c5c2e6c).

Comment: How do you even authenticate on VSTS? According to the link, you need to open IE...

Comment: The link seems to be broken by now and searching for `onedrive powershell` doesn't yield any results - do you happen to have an updated link available?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can publish directly by publish build artifacts task.

Publish build artifacts task only support two types:

> Server: store artifacts in team services.
>
> File share: copy artifacts to a file share that must be accessible
>   from the build agent.

- #### If you have local folder to sync with onedrive

  You can use **copy files** task  by these settings:

  Source Folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)`

  Target folder: the local path where you sync with onedirve library.
- #### If you haven't local folder to sync with onedrive

  You can use **power shell script** task to [upload file/folders by REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659726.aspx).

Comment: Do I have local folders with Visual Studio Online / Team Services? I thought that not...

Comment: No, the folder to sync with onedrive is a common folder, you can refer this link to set https://windows.gadgethacks.com/how-to/set-up-onedrive-sync-files-across-all-your-devices-windows-10-0162961/.